# How does Inspirobot random insprational quote generator work

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language

[Inspirobot](https://inspirobot.me) is a website that generates random inspirational quotes.  I would like to understand how this was built (training data used, algorithms used to create the sentences, etc).

Please reference python libraries if there are some specific ones (outside of sci-kit learn, etc).